# How can I make an image classification system that is easy to interact with using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to make an image classification service, that can detect whether or not a light is green or red.

I would like to send images to a ruby on rails application, which will then call the 'AI' magic which has the model to perform this recognition.

I have little experience with AI and am searching for a suitable, simple way to make this happen.

Experience and pointers on the creation of this image classification model would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tensorflow.rb to build a simple image recognition software, and once you implement it adapt it to your needs. You can find it here: https://github.com/somaticio/tensorflow.rb

Tensorflow.rb is just a port of tensorflow to ruby, there's an introductory which you can find [here](https://medium.com/@Arafat./introducing-tensorflow-ruby-api-e77a477ff16e). A second approach would be to build a microservice that receives an image (a file basically) and uses normal tensorflow which you can use with python.

A third approach would be to use an external microservice, such as microsoft's image recognition API and store the results of that API call itself. The downside of this is that you'd most likely have to pay in the long run for this service. The upside is that you'll have a well trained algorithm working, while also reducing overhead of development by externalizing this service to a third party.

Comment: Which would be the best approach in your mind? If I plan on having the server side of this application running in rails, it perhaps makes most sense to use Tensorflow.rb, as it will be one less hop.

The Tensorflow introductory guide looses me fairly quickly, as it is scoped to quite a low level. Do you know of a good guide for the ruby port for my particular aim?

Comment: I think it depends on the stage your product is currently in. If you just want to validate a hypothesis, I'd go with something that requires little work, so that you're able to see whether it works or not. Based on this I'd try to look for something which already exists.
In case you want to have something tailor-made for your software, I'd definitely go with standard tensorflow. I'm not 100% sure about how completed the ruby port is implemented right now, there's lots of material online to learn about how to use tensorflow. Luckily what you need is some of the most used use-cases for IA